# How to embed user photo upload form in a page of Drupal 7 site

Tags: 7, nodes, users

I want to embed user photo(avatar) upload form in a node page like this: node--37.tpl.php so a user can change or upload their profile picture by visiting a particular node.
Can't understand what to do, reading some api documentation like [function form_load_include](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_load_include/7) with no luck.
Also i found an amazing snippet [here](http://d.danylevskyi.com/node/7) but how to use it as a form?

```
$uid = 3;
$account = user_load($uid);

// suppose that a source user picture is located in the 'sites/default/files/upics'     directory.
// get image information
$image_path = 'public://upics/userpic.jpg';
$image_info = image_get_info($image_path);

// create file object
$file = new StdClass();
$file->uid = $uid;
$file->uri = $image_path;
$file->filemime = $image_info['mime_type'];
$file->status = 0; // Yes! Set status to 0 in order to save temporary file.
$file->filesize = $image_info['file_size'];

// standard Drupal validators for user pictures
$validators = array(
  'file_validate_is_image' => array(),
  'file_validate_image_resolution' => array(variable_get('user_picture_dimensions',     '85x85')),
  'file_validate_size' => array(variable_get('user_picture_file_size', '30') * 1024),
);

// here all the magic :)  
$errors = file_validate($file, $validators);
if (empty($errors)) {
  file_save($file);
  $edit['picture'] = $file;
  user_save($account, $edit);
}
```

Please give me some ideas to get started, your help is really appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

- Open node--37.tpl.php
- locate the container(div) where should be placed a form and use [drupal_get_form()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/7) function.

example:

```
<div class="some-class">
<?php print render(drupal_get_form('MY_FORM_ID')); ?>
</div>
```